# Computed columns with null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a view (using MS sql 2008) with creates a calculated field as a `COLUMN1 + COLUMN2`. Everything is fine and dandy but: Both `COLUMN1` and `COLUMN2` can be NULL.

I want to follow the following rule:

- 2 + 2 = 4
- 2 + NULL = 2
- NULL + 2 = 2
- 0 + 0 =  0
- NULL + NULL = NULL

If I use ISNULL(column2, 0), then all the rules will be followed but not the last one.

How do I need to create the view

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.test
AS
SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, (????????) AS CALCULATEDCOL FROM dbo.TabTest;
GO
```

Comment: how would then be `NULL + 2`? is it equal to `nULL` or `2`?

Answer (score 3):

```
create view dbo.test AS 
    select
        column1, 
        column2,
        case
            when column1 is null and column2 is null then null
            -- or when isnull(column1, column2) is null then null
            else isnull(column1, 0) + isnull(column2, 0)
        end as CALCULATEDCOL 
    from dbo.TabTest
```

Comment: to avoid the -OR- if you could also use ...WHEN ISNULL(column1,column2) IS NULL THEN...

Comment: I've just write it as a option you can use either `when column1 is null and column2 is null then null` or `when isnull(column1, column2) is null then null`

Comment: ah, see that now... wow, I somehow ignored the commented part completely :(  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

```
CASE  
      WHEN COALESCE(COLUMN1, COLUMN2) IS NULL THEN NULL
      ELSE ISNULL(COLUMN1, 0) + ISNULL(COLUMN2, 0)
END
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this without a `case` statement:

```
select coalesce(column1+column2,
                coalesce(column1, 0) + column2,
                column1 + coalesce(column2, 0)
               )
```

(The function `coalesce` is equivalent to `isnull`, except `coalesce` is standard SQL and can take more than two arguments.)

There is no disadvantage to using the `case` statement.  I'm just offering this as an alternative.

Comment: This solution works, but it's far less readable than using `case`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `CASE` expression instead. Like so:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.test AS 
  SELECT 
    COLUMN1, 
    COLUMN2,
    CASE  
      WHEN COLUMN1 IS NULL AND COLUMN2 IS NULL THEN NULL
      WHEN COLUMN1 IS NULL THEN 0 + COLUMN2
      WHEN COLUMN2 IS NULL THEN 0 + COLUMN1
      ELSE COLUMN1 + COLUMN2
    END AS CALCULATEDCOL 
  FROM dbo.TabTest; 
GO
```

Comment: This solution does not address the scenario where both values are not null.

Comment: You don't even need 'WHEN COLUMN1 IS NULL AND COLUMN2 IS NULL THEN NULL' I guess it helps readability though

Comment: I think you need to evaluate `WHEN COLUMN1 IS NULL AND COLUMN2 IS NULL THEN NULL` first, or you don't even need it at all.  If you evaluate `WHEN COLUMN1 IS NULL` first, if COLUMN2 is also NULL, you'll get 0 + NULL which gives you the net result of NULL.

Comment: No, you have already checked in the first part of the case. When column1 is null. It will never get to the last part

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: The three conditions provided in the case all test for null. If both columns are 1, for instance, the result will be null because none of the three conditions are true.

Comment: @Allan - Yes you are right, I forgot the `ELSE COLUMN1 + COLUMN2` part.

Comment: @Allan yes, I am sorry. I deleted my previous comment, you are right

Comment: Note after you changed the script. You don't need the first part of the case. Why would you make an extra check. If they are both null, 0 + column2 is still null

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - If I removed the first extra check `WHEN COLUMN1 IS NULL AND COLUMN2 IS NULL THEN NULL` then if the `COLUMN1 IS NULL` it won't proceed to the next case when.

Comment: what do you think 'WHEN COLUMN1 IS NULL THEN 0 + COLUMN2' will return when column2 is null ????? Yes, null which is exactly what the first part of your case returns

Answer (score 1):

it is more simple than people would expect, using CASE for this question is a waste when there is a standard function called COALESCE, just replace your questionmarks with this:

```
COALESCE(col1 + col2, col1, col2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` to handle the last condition:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.test
AS
 SELECT column1,
        column2,
        CASE
            WHEN column1 IS NULL
                THEN column2 + 0
            WHEN column2 IS NULL
                THEN column1 + 0
            WHEN column1 IS NOT NULL AND column2 IS NOT NULL
                THEN column1 + column2
        ELSE NULL
        END AS calculatedcol
  FROM  dbo.tabtest;
```

Comment: When both columns are null, I will get 0 then, and not null.

Comment: If both columns are not null (i.e. if both are 1), this solution will return zero.

Answer (score 0):

You rule seems to be "Treat nulls as zero unless both fields are null, in which case, return null." I would approach this with a `case`, to separate the two rules:

```
CASE WHEN column1 is null and column2 is null then null
ELSE ISNULL(column1,0) + ISNULL(column2,0)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a case system, you can handle when both values are null from when either of them is NULL

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.test
AS
  SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, 
    CASE WHEN (COLUMN1 IS NULL AND COLUMN2 IS NULL) THEN NULL 
    ELSE ISNULL(COLUMN1,0)+ISNULL(COLUMN2,0) 
    END  AS CALCULATEDCOL 
FROM dbo.TabTest;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) keyword to achieve this.

Something on these lines

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN COLUMN1 IS NULL AND COLUMN2 IS NULL THEN NULL 
WHEN COLUMN1 IS NULL AND... etc...
```

Comment: `ISNULL` requires two arguments and shouldn't be used to test for null values. Also, you should format code as code when providing answers.